# Connecting to Oracle XE edition with sqlplus but without password

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

Yes, I've seen https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/140147

The command `sqlplus / as sysdba` mentioned in this answer and elsewhere on the web still asks me for password on my installation:

```
Oracle Linux 7.7

oracle-database-xe-21c-1.0-1.x86_64
```

However, that command still asks me for password:

```
[root@localhost ~]# su - oracle
Last login: Fri Sep  2 09:01:34 EDT 2022 on pts/0

[oracle@localhost bin]$ export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE

[oracle@localhost bin]$ cd /opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/bin/

[oracle@localhost bin]$ ./sqlplus  / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Sep 2 09:02:24 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


Enter user-name:
```

I don't really need any database in particular. My job is gathering some meta information about Oracle installation such as version, configuration file, database files dir etc.

Yes, I can read some of the info from oracle system files on RedHat and similar (Oracle Linux is compiled from RH sources, it's very similar to RH). Still, some info is only available in `sqlplus`.

**UPDATE**:

Regarding shell environment I've done as `oracle` user is:

`export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE`

```
[oracle@localhost bin]$ ./oraenv 
ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ? 
ORACLE_HOME = [/home/oracle] ? /opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE
The Oracle base has been set to /opt/oracle
```

However, following command still asks me for password:

```
[oracle@localhost bin]$ ./sqlplus -l / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Sep 2 09:24:55 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


SP2-0751: Unable to connect to Oracle.  Exiting SQL*Plus
[oracle@localhost bin]$ 
[oracle@localhost bin]$ ./sqlplus  / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Sep 2 09:24:59 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified


Enter user-name:
```

Comment: It's asking you for a user name, not a password, because the first login attempt fails. If you add the `-l` flag then it won't prompt you for a second login attempt. But the first one will still fail - have you set your environment up properly, e.g. with `oraenv`? It looks like you maybe don't have `ORACLE_SID` (or `TWO_TASK`) set?

Comment: @AlexPoole Geez Alex I have no idea what you're talking about, I'm totally new to Oracle. If you turn your comment into an answer and it works for me, I'll accept it. Pls see update.

Comment: You need to *source* `oraenv`, as `. ./oraenv` or `source ./oraenv`- otherwise anything it sets only exists for the duration of the script. (That isn't an Oracle thing, [it's a shell thing](https://superuser.com/q/176783/45140).) Also in your update you ran `sqlplus` twice, the first time with `-l` which did not prompt for credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Enter user-name:" prompt is appearing because the initial login attempt failed, with ORA-12162. By default it will try to log in up to three times, prompting for credentials each time - except the first time, since you provided the first set to try on the command line.

If you do `./sqlplus  -l / as sysdba` then it will only try to log in once, instead of reprompting on error (to slightly paraphrase the usage notes).

But it will still get that ORA-12162 error the first time.

Your environment isn't set up properly. You've manually set `ORACLE_HOME`, but not any other [Oracle-related environment variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/configuring-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-5A2953BF-9E2F-450B-AFBA-EE2846C59B5E); specifically here `ORACLE_SID` (or maybe `TWO_TASK` to connect remotely). You probably want to set other things like `PATH` properly too.

The Oracle home `bin` directory includes an `oraenv` script that you can source that ([rather than just executing it](https://superuser.com/q/176783/45140)) to set the environment up for a specific local DB, using

```
. ${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/oraenv
```

or

```
source ${ORACLE_HOME}/bin/oraenv
```

... but you might prefer to set things manually.

> I don't really need any database in particular. My job is gathering some meta information about Oracle installation such as version, configuration file, database files dir etc.

You already effectively know the database software version, 21c, from the `ORACLE_HOME` path, but there is an `oraversion` executable in the `bin` dir that lets you get more detailed information about the version of the Oracle binaries in that home.

The rest of the information is specific to a database. You might be able to find a text `pfile`, or more likely a binary `spfile`, but is you're using ASM those might not be on a normal local filesystem. really you do need to connect to the database to interrogate it for file and directory location etc.

(It's also possible that the database version could be slightly different to the binaries version - it shouldn't be really but I think it's possible mid-upgrade if some of the upgrade scripts haven't been run. I might be wrong though. But query `v$version` anyway to be sure.)

> the goal is to detect software systems such as Oracle installed on all endpoints where the agent is working

If the server is acting as an Oracle database server then it should have an `oratab` file, usually as `/etc/oratab` or `/var/opt/oracle/oratab` or similar - you might need to `locate` it.

That lists all of the local databases in colon-delimited form, e.g. `orcl:/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE:Y`, with the first two elements being the `ORACLE_SID` and `ORACLE_HOME` values. (The third is an auto-start flag). So you can parse that file to identify the Oracle home directory (or directories; there could be more than one), and the SID value(s) to pass to `oraenv` for each version and that you can attempt to log in to.

Comment: On "You already effectively know the database version, 12c, from the ORACLE_HOME path": well that's just my dev environment, in production the script will extract attributes mentioned and send them to certain software detection and cataloging system (the goal is to detect software systems such as Oracle installed on all endpoints where the agent is working and collect sw attrs), so I won't know the version beforehand. I'll have to extract stuff like ORACLE_HOME from RPM DB or scripts installed by Oracle RPM package.

Comment: But you need to know where to run `oraenv` from. I guess you can `locate` it, or get an initial home location from `/etc/oratab` or some other place `oratab` happens to live - but you could also have more than one home, and more than one DB on a server, each with a different home - though I think that's rare now, for standalone DBs. The `oratab` will also tell you which `ORACLE_SID` values are valid to pass into `oraenv`.

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you for info on `/etc/oratab`. I've accepted your answer but If you add this and "You need to source oraenv, as . ./oraenv or source ./oraenv- otherwise anything it sets only exists for the duration of the script. " to your answer for posterity it would be nice I think.

Comment: OK, I'd mentioned sourcing but I've made that clearer, and put some info about `oratab` in there too.